# Variables in R how, central limit

Tags: r, histogram

I have following task:
Assume the population of interest can be modeled by a Bernoulli distribution with
p = 0.5.
For each sample size n simulate r = 5, 000 draws (by using a for loop over (i in
1:r)) from that Bernoulli distribution with p = 0.5 and calculate the standardized
sample mean for each draw.

The last histogram looks good with a curve, but 1st and 2ns are wrong. Maybe someone han help me with this. Thanks in advance for your time!

I have done following:

```
set.seed(2005)
x1 <- rbinom(5000,3,0.5)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))


hist(x=x1,
  main=expression(paste(" Random Variables with",size,"=1 and",prob,"=0.5")),  
  sub="Standardized value of smple sample avearge",
  xlab="n=3", ylab="Probability", probability = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(x), sd=sd(x)), add = TRUE, col="blue")
```

Answer (score -1):

Essentially what happened in the first two panels is that for a small `n` the histogram breaks were calculated in an ungraceful manner. You can fix that by letting the breaks depend on the data range. Here, I chose the breaks depending on whether the range of the data was smaller than 10. If this is `TRUE`, manually calculate breaks, otherwise use the default `"Sturges"` algorithm for breaks.

```r
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

N <- c(2, 5, 25, 100)

for (i in seq_along(N)) {
  set.seed(2015 + i)
  n <- N[i]
  
  xx <- rbinom(10000, n, 0.78)
  if (diff(range(xx)) < 10) {
    breaks <- seq(floor(min(xx)), ceiling(max(xx)))
  } else {
    breaks <- "Sturges"
  }
  
  hist(
    x = xx, breaks = breaks,
    main=expression(paste("Bernoulli Random Variables with",size,"=1 and",prob,"=0.78")), 
    sub = "Standardized value of sample average",
    xlab = paste0("n=",n), ylab = "Probability", probability = TRUE
  )
  curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(xx), sd=sd(xx)), add = TRUE, col="blue")
}
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi teunbrand, thanks fot your help, but in your example the sample is not standardized. I forgot to mention that I need additionally: to write a code in R that replicates the illustration of the central limit theorem (CLT) for the standardized sample average of n Bernoulli random variables. that makes me crazy

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Statistical questions are more at home in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). The statistics of your question is not my area of expertise, but you might find the following useful: https://mse.redwoods.edu/darnold/math15/spring2013/R/Activities/MeanVarStd.html